# I am getting "custom program error: 0x3b" on updating the metadata of a NFT using the token metadata program?

Tags: solana, metaplex

I am trying to mint and NFT and update the metadata of that NFT but when i try updating the metadata of that NFT i get this error [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Error Usually happens when the NFT is marked as not mutable and to check if your NFT is mutable or not you can use the token address of that NFT and check its metadata from Solana Explorer or SolScan. If the `isMutable` variable in the metadata is set to 1 then it means that the data of that NFT is mutable if its set to 0 then its immutable.

So the simple answer to this question is to mark your NFT as mutable when creating it so that you can update it later if you have the update authority over that NFT.

Answer (score 0):

Here is where you can find the error code: `0x3b` => `59`

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/master/token-metadata/program/src/error.rs#L253